# changing child tag name in an xml using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to read and change one of the tag name (pin code) in the xml file. I tried below but it is not working.

xml file (just displaying one record here) -

```
<FILE>
    <INSTANCE>
        <UserID>100</UserID>
        <UserName>ABC</UserName>
        <PINCode>110060</PINCode>
        <FaxNumber />
    </INSTANCE>
</FILE>
```

what i tried -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("exchcds_Users.xml")
for elem in tree.findall("INSTANCE\PINCode"):
    elem.tag = "PPPP"
tree.write("users.xml")
```

Comment: Your XPath is wrong, to start, so your `findall()` returns an empty list and your loop does nothing.

Comment: @sreekiran sorry i gave wrong tag...but even after doing correction to xpath its not working -    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("exchcds_Users.xml")
for elem in tree.findall("INSTANCE\PINCode"):
    elem.tag = "PPPP"
tree.write("users.xml")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you provided backslash `\` instead of forward slash `/`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("xml_sample.xml")
for elem in tree.findall("INSTANCE/PINCode"):
    print(elem)
    elem.tag = "PPPP"
tree.write("users.xml")
```